# Pods-resources.sh fails to run momc for xcdatamodeld after updating to OSX 10.10

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, macos

I keep on getting this error after updating to osx yosemite:

```
/Users/marwan/development/Tagthis/Tagthis/Tag.xcdatamodeld: Compilation failed for data model at path '/Users/marwan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tag-bowkjsbadldfleczpwolpimvwvjg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tag.app/Tag.momd/Tag3.mom'
```

I tried all the solutions suggested on stack over flow but nothing worked

Comment: Same for me! It unexpectedly became once after system reboot and nothing helps